# Is it possible to set "Do not mail" -- but only for a time

Tags: privacy

I was asked an interesting question the other day: is it possible to set time-bound privacy settings? (Such as "Do not email for 3 months" or similar). Perhaps an extension that is out there?

Comment: could you do it with some sort of combination of Activity and CiviRules?

Answer (score 2):

https://civicrm.org/extensions/do-not-contact-until

May not be compatible with latest version of CiviCRM as it hasn’t been updated for a number of years.

Comment: Thanks! I am contacting the author to see if it's known to be functional or not.

Comment: Hi all, I'm the author of this extension, and Laryn did contact me. For everyone else's information, we moved away from CiviCRM in 2016 and are no longer maintaining the extensions we made. It hasn't been tested with anything more up to date at least by me.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is available yet in community via extension but its a good very feature to implement a cron job via as extension.